preposition: in [in one flavour] and [in different sizes]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) We have some boxes of chips for you to share. They are only in one flavour.
(1b) We have some boxes of chips for you to share. They are only one flavour.
(2a) We have some free shoes for our participants. They are in different sizes.
(2b) We have some free shoes for our participants. They are different sizes.
Do you need "in"? Thanks.

What are your own thoughts about each? What leads you to suppose what you do suppose? How is this set of made-up remarks relevant to learning English? What research have you done to work out whatever it is that you are puzzled by?

You could use of instead of in. Both are more formal than the versions without.

In colloquial American English, the preposition is optional, and more frequently dropped than used, according to Ngram.
Caveat: Ngram allows up to three words, so the query is based on in only one flavor and in one flavor. Also note slightly different results using UK spelling, 'flavour'.
For whatever reason, "in different sizes," with preposition included, sounds more natural to me, and that feeling is somewhat supported by this (again, somewhat mismatched) Ngram query.
Yes, these are inconsistent results, but then consider that the "rules" of English imply ghoti spells the word "fish". Or, as R W Emerson put it, "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds." sigh
